# Play/Scala/Anorm saving answer to variable number of questions

Tags: json, playframework, anorm

I am using the play framework with anorm/pgsql to create a survey application. Responses to questions are saved in JSONB format since some responses have nested response types. I am able to save the response to a single question by POST'ing to a route defined in my routes.conf file, but am having trouble thinking how I would go about creating the logic to accept the logic for several questions at once. Bascically, when the 'Next' button on the survey is clicked, the answers to 2-n number of questions will be posted. I have code as follows, but am currently unsure how to test it with a POST:

```
  def jsonSaveMany(userResponses:List[Response],email:String,id:Long) = {
    DB.withConnection{
      implicit c =>
       for (response <- userResponses) jsonSave(response,response.useremail,response.id)

    }
  }
  def jsonSave(usersResponse:Response,email:String,id:Long) = {
    DB.withConnection{
      implicit c =>
        val userResponse=usersResponse.response
        val userJson:String = s"""{"response":"$userResponse"}"""
        val pgObject = new PGobject();
        pgObject.setType("jsonb")
        pgObject.setValue(userJson)
        SQL(s"INSERT INTO responses(response,useremail,questionid) values ({userResp},{eMail},{quesId})")
          .on('userResp -> anorm.Object(pgObject), 'eMail -> s"$email",'quesId -> id)
          .executeInsert(SqlParser.scalar[String].singleOpt)
    }
  }
```

The view file I have been testing using the Twirl templating engine takes a parameter of `@(responseForm: Form[Response])` but basically I need to be able to feed it a List of type Form[Response] where the List can range from 2-n questions. I can't seem to figure out a better way to formulate this, or to even test if this logic is working. I am unsure how to even create a List of Form[Response] in the scala.html files I am using to test with.

An alternative approach I have been trying more recently is using JSON inception in the companion object of the response case class like so: `implicit val responseReads = Json.reads[Response]` but i am unable to test posting to this via CURL as I get no response whatsoever when I POST to the route I defined for this function.

My questions is basically, how can I utilize a map type function that takes each question and saves the response to the DB and test it via either a simple front end GUI or a basic CURL from the terminal?

Comment: Which code have you tried?

Comment: i have implemented both the implicit Json.reads as well as the jsonSaveMany() functions. My problem is basically how to check if it is working... when I curl from the terminal I don't see output in the same manner as when i use the browser even for routes I already have working. If i could have a simple front end text input that submitted JSON on 'Submit' that would help me know if my implicit reader is working or not

Comment: the problem I have with the jsonSaveMany() function is I am not sure how to include  List of response types of variable length in the scala.html files with which I can post data back to the server. I have implemented a single response GUI in scala.html files that use the jsonSave function and this works for a single question response.

Comment: i tried adding a single text field and putting JSON object directly in it and posting it like {"useremail":"my@email.com","response":"myAnswer"} put I get internal server error for POST noSuchElementException None.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I discarded the jsonSaveMany() function and did the for-comprehension in the ResponseController file rather than my DBController file.

In order to test this effectively, i used a ws.URL Future call, that directly called my own API endpoint. this way I could simply authenticate and test via a simple link in a scala.html page that posted a dummy sequence of JSON objects to test if they posted successfully. my unit test looked like this:

```
def postJSONTest = SecuredAction {
    request =>
      val datum1 = Json.obj(
        "questionid" -> 14,
        "id" -> 14,
        "response" -> "godzilla"
      )

      val datum2 = Json.obj(
        "questionid" -> 15,
        "id" -> 15,
        "response" -> "van halen"
      )

      val data = JsArray(Seq(datum1,datum2))
      val email = request.identity.email.get
      val url = s"http://localhost:9000/response/save/$email"
      val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(url).post(data)
      Redirect(routes.ResponseController.responses).flashing("success" -> "JSON posted!")
  }
```

I am using silhouette for authentication/authorization, and request.identity.email.get retrieves the email of the currently logged-in user.

When I append the datum to data it renders as a json array like this:

```
[{"questionid":14,"id":14,"response":"godzilla"},{"questionid":15,"id":15,"response":"van halen"}]
```

My Response case class contains a implicit json reader that appears like this:

```
case class Response (questionid:Long,
                     id:Long,
                     response:String)


object Response {
  /**
   * the implicit reader responseReads converts incoming JSON with
   * keys equal to the property names of the Response case class
   * into a format that is easily saved to pgSQL
   */
  implicit val responseReads=Json.reads[Response]
```

And my function in my ResponseController.scala file contains a for-comprehension that converts each element in the array of JSON objects into a Response object using the implicit JSON reads method. This puts it into a format that is easily saved into pgSQL.

```
  def postResponse(email:String) = Action {
    implicit request =>
        val json = request.body.asJson.get
        val jsonList = json.as[List[JsObject]]
        for (item <- jsonList) {
            val oneItem = item.as[Response]
            Response.jsonSave(oneItem,email)
            }
        Ok("success")
  }
```

This was my general approach, the part that really helped me was the use of `Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(url).post(data)` to post the JSON data directly within my app. I tried using CURL and the chrome extension POSTMAN but was having trouble with these methods. Hope this answer can help others using play/scala.